# Clojure web application starting [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it (on reload/undeploy). How to resolve in Clojure code?

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, clojure

I've noticed that on continuous redeploys of the application, I've observed some memory leak when I am using VisualVM 1.3.8 to figure out why does the Tomcat installation occasionally run into PermGem problems. And I discovered through VisualVM and also the following errors constantly appearing during testing:

```
04-Nov-2015 16:35:27.828 WARNING [http-apr-8000-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [admin-rrs-sm] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

and also

```
04-Nov-2015 16:29:24.624 WARNING [http-apr-8000-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [admin-rrs-sm] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
```

That for some reason, even though the old application context has been "destroyed," the entire application is still being held in the memory, and, using VisualVM, it turns out that `contextClassLoader` which is the closest to the GC root is being referred to by `com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread`. For latest test, here was the stack trace:

```
Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:142)
 com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
```

Since my initial code before it packaged as a WAR was in Clojure, I'm not sure how exactly I would be dealing with this. For a start, nothing happened when I decided to try and remove the MySQL connector .jar from the WAR and then deploy the application this way while having the same .jar inside the Tomcat's `/lib` folder. I still kept getting the same errors. On a slightly less related note, Eclipse's MAT tells me the biggest objects are `clojure.lang.LazySeq`, `clojure.lang.Namespace` and `clojure.lang.Var`, is this normal and is this actually related to my problem?

EDIT: Casual OQL scraping of my heap dumps has led me to discover an absurd amount of threads being kept in memory, presumably because the `AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread` was never cleared out despite being so-called "deregistered" by Tomcat. Even if I were to define some sort of `destroy` handler in the `:ring { }` options object of my `project.clj`, checking the existing documentation of `org.clojure/java.jdbc` and not putting `mysql-connector-java` into the WAR file does not give me a single direction. I'm not asking for any code, but rather I'd just like some pointers as to where to go about starting off so I can implement a `destroy` handler myself.